# Vertically align dynamic divs within parent div with only HTML

Tags: html, css

Here is our html:

```
<div id="1" class="right">
    <div class="top"><img src=".png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="content">Some dynamic text</div>
    <div class="bottom"><img src=".png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

And here's our CSS:

```
.right{position:relative; top:-304px; width:170px; height:191px;}
.content{background:url(.png) repeat-y; width:170px;}
```

How do we vertically align the content of #1 to always be at the bottom? Design and technical limitations mean we cannot use any CSS table properties or JavaScript.

Comment: Are you talking about sticking `.bottom` to the... bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tY3Dh/)  (*scroll to bootom of fiddle to see the image*)

```
.right {
    position:relative;
    top:304px;
    width:170px;
    height:191px;
}
.content {
    background:url(.png) repeat-y;
    width:170px;
}
.bottom {
    position:absolute; /* this is the key */
    bottom:0;/* this is the key */
}
.bottom >img {
    width:100%;
}
```

**to do** : use `absolute` child, of a `relative` parent div

**Added explanation :** since your `.right` has `top:-304px;` and the whole div has no content and `height : 191px`, so the entire markup has `height = -113px` (*-304+191*), so you wont be able to see anything...change the height to see it.
 [**see what i am talking about**](http://jsfiddle.net/tY3Dh/1/)

**EDIT**

Assuming you have **fixed height div**, [here is a solution without using position](http://jsfiddle.net/tY3Dh/2/)

```
.right {
    width:170px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.content {
    background:url(.png) repeat-y;
    width:170px;
}
.bottom {
    margin-top:300px;
    margin-bottom: -200px;    /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height(200px) */
}
.bottom >img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I need position:relative to position .right relative to other elements on the page, so can't change to position:absolute. Any other ideas???

Comment: do you have fixed height of the container?? i mean does `.right` has fixed height?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the class `.right` to this:

```
.right{
     position:absolute; 
     bottom: 0; 
     width:170px; 
     height:191px;
 }
```

I hope this help you :)

Comment: though its same as my answer....but its ok....congrats on your first +10 rep...welcome to SO :)